# Using ForLoop method to assign properties for 9UIButtons?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've been trying to avoid `for loop` all day but I can't anymore. Guys, how do I do the following:  I have 9 `UIButtons` called :`imageCallerButton1`,`imageCallerButton2`,`imageCallerButton3,etc` is there a way to change the radius using a for loop instead of adding 18lines?

```
for (int i =9; i<=9; ++i) {
    imageCallerButton1.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    imageCallerButton1.clipsToBounds = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array or another collection before you can use a `for` loop:

```
NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: imageCallerButton1, imageCallerButton2, ...];
for (UIButton *btn in buttons) {
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    btn.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: Very nice way! what if I want to use int [i] ?

Comment: @iMohammad You can use `[buttons objectAtIndex:i]`.

Comment: I think you mean `UIButton *`. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using an array of imageCallerButtons.

```
imgCB = new imageCallerButton [9];
for(int i = 0; i < imgCB.length; i++){
   imageCallerButton[i].layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    imageCallerButton[i].clipsToBounds = YES;

}
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. `imageCallerButton` is a variable name, not a type. And then you go on and use both `imageCallerButton` and `imgCB` as names for the array--but you appear to be using Java syntax, which is not anything like Objective-C or C syntax when it comes to arrays.